# Разделение длинных слов

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Появился такой вопрос, на сайте стоит обработка длинных слов

```
$message = preg_replace('/([^\s]{55})/' , "$1 ", $message);
```

Но если в поле вставить ссылку, допустим, 60 символов, то получится нечто вида:

href="ссылка

И она также станет с пробелом, следовательно, станет нерабочей. Как это можно поправить?

Comment: Как-то так:  

    /((?:^|\s)(?!https?:\/\/)[^\s]{55})/

Comment: > Как это можно поправить?

Разбором только содержимого тегов, регуляркой или парсером.

Comment: @ReinRaus, не сработало

Comment: @singmen, а Вы пробовали?  
Вот пример, как обрезаются строки, длиннее 10 символов:  

    ((?:\s|\G)(?!https?:\/\/)[^\s]{10})

http://regex101.com/r/mP6eD1/1  
Смотреть надо на группы, которые матчатся в правом столбце. К сожалению, этот регекс-сайт не позволяет делать реплейс. Было бы нагляднее.  

--------------

Приведите целевой текст, на котором регулярное выражение не сработало.

Comment: @ReinRaus, да, проблема была во мне, в базу после post'a отправлялась ссылка  и сразу же преобразовывалась в кликабельную, ну, а далее уже при "вытаскивании" из базы я применял регулярку, а т.к. она имела вид href="http она не срабатывала, поправил - заработало, спасибо =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] splitted = img.toString().split("http://");
                //so index 1 is the url and we can just append http:// back on the beginning to get the whole url
                String url1 = "http://" + splitted[1];
```

Используйте этот метод, почитайте о нем, думаю, поможет. Разрезаешь ссылку до пробела (если, конечно, примерно знаешь, что там будет) и после пробела. Потом клеишь с помощью этого же метода.

Comment: Метод split

Comment: допустим, вы обрезаете до 150 символов. Из обрезанного текста, найти ссылки, если такая найдена и не заканчивается на /a.  тогда определить позицию ее конца. обрезать текст до нее. Найти ссылки с помощью рег. вырвжений, в сети куча примеров.

Comment: @djbolya, вас не смущает отсутствие любого намёка на C# в вопросе?